# Better alternative for x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest header

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers

With the evolution of JS we (modern js app developers) mostly use JSON to transfer data. Moreover [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequest) method also became legacy because [Fetch API](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/the-fetch-api-2c962591f5c) is replacing it.

We neither transfer `XML` nor use  `XMLHttpRequest()` but we still add the `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest` header to inform the server about the async request type.

Is there a better, modern header for this purpose. All research leads to this legacy header.

Comment: Browser does not do that. We "add" it. We can always modify that header. Modern js apps do not use XML request. So by definition it is legacy. (Not deprecated) We are out of XML era but we still use the terminology. I think you get the point.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - `We are out of XML era` no, unless by "we" you mean "you" and whatever organisation you code for, but, "we" (as in me and the company I work for)  use XML all the time, since the government endpoints we use still use it